# sending data as HttpParams but going as formData to the server

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I am working on Angular 8

I am trying to send data to server as  **HttpParams but getting 502 error**

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 502, statusText: "Bad
>   Gateway"
>
> In **browser's Network's Header i can see that data is going as
>   formData**

I am sharing my code

**service file**

```
userlogin(userid, smpassword) {

const params = new HttpParams()
.set('user_id', userid)
.set('sm_password', smpassword);

console.log(params);


return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'user/login', params);

  }
```

**component**

```
 login() {

    const email =  this.Userlogin.get('email').value;
    const password = this.Userlogin.get('password').value;
    this.rest.userlogin(email, password).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    );

    //  this.route.navigateByUrl('/pendingapproval');

  }
```

Comment: An HTTP request/response body that represents serialized parameters, per the MIME type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: @enno.void how i will write type

Comment: @enno.void   body.toString(),
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    }

Answer (score 2):

Note that on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)  the post method suppose that you provide posted object in the second parameter.

```
  post(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: HttpObserve; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "text" | "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; } = {}): Observable<any>
```

So when you are sending your parameters it's actually interpreted as  the posted object

try with a dummy object

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'user/login', mydummyObject, params);
```

Or even better try with  `this.http.get` since you do not have any object to post!!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('user_id', userid);
params = params.append('sm_password', smpassword);
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'user/login', {params:params });
```